# IBM HS22 Blade loses connectivity intermittently

Tags: windows-server-2008, ibm, blade-server

My IBM HS22 Blade loses connectivity intermittently. It happens randomly every few hours and lasts just a few minutes. The connection is restored without any action taken.

Problem is very similar to [this one](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-5070727) except that I have an HS22 blade running Win2008 R2 SP1 and with the latest broadcom driver installed.

Note that:

1. Blades are not on the same subnet as the AMM
2. It happens on 2 blades, the other 2 blades do not have this problem.
3. When the connection is lost I can still access a blade from the other blades, but not from outside the chassis.

This concerns a production env. Help needed urgently, thank you.

Comment: This sounds like some kind of arping or networking issue between the upstream devices and your bladecenter since the other blades can maintain connectivity. What kind of networking fabrics are involved and what is upstream?

Comment: Is STP turned on on the switch ports? Can you check if it could have fired?

Comment: Call IBM Support.  It's a production system, and if you've got blades in a production environment without support, then you're a tit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the latest firmware packages.  I had this problem and it was fixed about a year ago.  Make sure that you work from the chassis down so that the blade firmware isn't newer than the chassis.